# XJC - ignore nillable=true

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, xjc

In order to avoid values being wrapped in `JAXBElement`, I am generating classes from XSD with the following bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <xjc:simple />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, there is a problem with `nillable` fields. For the following XSD:

```
<!-- ... -->
<xsd:complexType name="getShortCustomerIn">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="fieldOne" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="fieldTwo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- ... -->
```

XJC will generate a class with fields:

```
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String fieldOne;
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
protected String fieldTwo;
```

When the `fieldTwo` is `null` then the request will contain a field with nil set to true:

```
<fieldOne>1001714</fieldOne>
<fieldTwo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

This is a problem for the WebService I integrate with since it chokes on such request, despite the fact that it is a valid XML. I have been said that when a field is `null` then it should not be present in the request at all. I realize that in order to meet that requirement, the generated classes cannot have the `@XmlElement` annotation's `nillable` attribute set to `true`.

Is there a way to ignore `nillable=true` in XSD files when generating classes with XJC?

Comment: did you had any luck with finding a solution?

Comment: No. I am using the regexp replace on WSDL input when generating classes in XJC. Let me know if you would like me to provide an example.

Comment: Oh man, I got same problem... Anything we can configure in the bindings file?

Comment: @Cleankod can you please help with your regexp solution?

Comment: @JatinTelang - I use Gradle's task (type `Copy`), which copies all of the WSDLs and filters them with `line.replaceAll 'nillable="true"', ''`. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files) for more information. Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Using XJC with jaxb2-basics-annotate worked for us

***pom.xml***

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jaxb-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema</schemaDirectory>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/schema/bindings</bindingDirectory>

                ...

                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    <arg>-XremoveAnnotation</arg>
                </args>

                ...

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

***bindings.xjb***

```
<bindings schemaLocation="sample.xsd">
    <bindings multiple="true" node="//xsd:element[@nillable='true']">
        <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable = false)</annox:annotate>          
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```